# Oracle Apex Interactive grid - how to add a row with a default value?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am currently working with Interactive Grids in Oracle Apex version 5.1.2 and I am having trouble figuring out how to add a row that automatically fills in one of the cells in the new row with a certain value, like the person's username or current date. I know in version 5.1.4 there is a section in the "Column Attributes" that allows me to put in a "Default value", but unfortunately I have to work in version 5.1.2 for this project. Does anyone know of a way to program the interactive grid so that every time I click the "Add Row" button it automatically fills in one of the cells in the new row with a certain predetermined value? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 5.1.1 and its Editable interactive grid offers the Default section in column's properties, so I believe that they didn't remove that functionality in 5.1.2 and then restored it in 5.1.4.

In other words, did you carefully check what's offered?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got it to work. Apparently if the "Source" section of the column attributes is set at "None", then the "Default" section is not available, but as soon as I changed the "Source" section to a "Database Column" then the "Default" section became available. Not sure why, but it works now. Thank you again.